# Is it better to use cache or use a spreadhsheet is google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing google apps script web apps that share data between end users who are using the app at the same time. 
I can write the data to a spreadsheet and allow others to read it, or put the data into script cache. 
Either way I need a server call. The data is not large....I was just wondering if cache was more server efficient/ faster / better practice ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache) the max time to live for data in a key 6 hours if you set the expiration, otherwise it lives in the cache for 10 mins. And also the maximum length of a key is 250 characters.

So it really depends on the architecture of your app, but using sheets as a database only perhaps isn't the best solution either, although it may be convenient in many cases.